# Adding a class to img tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, image

I am a learning javascript guy and I am trying to add the Image Hover Shadow Effect With CSS to my images and for that to work , I have to add an class to all my img tags , which is not possible manually so i am trying to write a javascript that does that and uses jquery , to do so .

it needs to add an class to img tag , such as this

From this

```
<img border="0"  height="75" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qhxaAUAJUVQ/TeocW4AuIiI/AAAAAAAABCo/IYy7hQ6-5VQ/s200/CSSEditLogo1.jpg" width="75"/>
```

to

```
<img border="0" class="imagedropshadow" height="75" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qhxaAUAJUVQ/TeocW4AuIiI/AAAAAAAABCo/IYy7hQ6-5VQ/s200/CSSEditLogo1.jpg" width="75"/>
```

Can anyone help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need the class. If you are planning to add a css class to all images and hook the shadow to it, you should be able to do it on the img tags directly.

```
img:hover{
 /*properties*/
}
```

Comment: THANKS THIS WORKS .. $("img").addClass("imagedropshadow");  this did not work though :( anyway THANKS !

Answer (score 18):

To add the class to all of the images on your page with jQuery:

```
$("img").addClass("imagedropshadow")
```

Without jQuery is is not very difficult either:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i;

for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].className += " imagedropshadow";
}
```

Comment: The activity of adding the class can be made simpler as follows

`images[i].classList.add('imagedropshadow');`

Answer (score 2):

give an ID to your image, let's say it's `imgId` and then write this jquery (if you want to add class to any specific img tag.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#imgId').addClass('imagedropshadow');
});
```

for all img tag simply use this;

```
$("img").addClass("imagedropshadow");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addClass` function with jQuery. See the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) for examples.

Comment: <script>
  $("img").addClass("imagedropshadow");
  </script>  so is this how i am supposed to do so ? it is not working

Comment: place your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ $("img").addClass("imagedropshadow"); });`

Comment: Thanks img:hover{
 /*properties*/
} worked jsfiddle is a gr8 site for debugging THANKS :) @Vivek @James Allardice

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('img').addClass('imagedropshadow');
```

But I suggest you that you add an id or general class into the img tag for selecting.